# Request.Security repainting the screener result when referring higher timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to get the Previous Day High and Low using **Request.Security**.
Here is my Code.

```
dh_func(sym) =>        
sema = ta.ema(close, ema_len)
//////////
/// Get Days High///

[h1,h2,l1,l2] = request.security(sym, 'D', [high[0],high[1],low[0],low[1]])    
//[h1,h2,l1,l2] = rp_security(sym, 'D')    
dh = (ta.cross(sema,math.max(h1,h2)) and isToday) or (ta.cross(close,math.max(h1,h2)) and isToday)
dl = (ta.cross(sema,math.min(l1,l2)) and isToday) or (ta.cross(close,math.min(l1,l2)) and isToday)
[dh,dl]
```

It is working fine, but when the candle closed in lower timeframe, the screener results are getting blank.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Note: I have also tried using **f_security()** it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is resolved, **f_security()** worked, issue was related to **ta.cross()**
now I am checking only

```
dh = close[1] > h1 and isToday
```

it worked.